# Bulk converting AD groupscope from domain local to universal

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

I have been testing the following command to convert individual "global groups" to "universal", it works fine.

```
dsmod group <GroupDN> -scope {L|G|U}
```

However, is there a way to convert a whole OU of global groups to universal, say 1500 groups.

Comment: ForEach-Object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638771/combining-group-object-and-foreach-object

Comment: Thanks Rob, I dont really get where I can apply the ForEach to this, if you dont mind can you explain.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this Powershell command, if you are running this from a Windows desktop client you will need to import the AD module which is part of RSAT.

In powershell you can use the -whatif flag to see what a command will do before applying it, converting groups should be as easy as listing them and then piping the list to the set-adgroup cmdlet.

the in Powershell `import module activedirectory`

Find all of the groups by specifying the search base, if the groups you want to convert are all in the same tree then don't search in subtrees.

```
Get-ADGroup -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "OU=StaffGroups,OU=Staff,DC=win" -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Security" -and GroupScope -eq "Global"}  | Set-ADGroup -GroupScope Universal -whatif
```

If the results with the -whatif command are satisfactory, them run the command again without the -whatif.